# Maven - build war with specific classes from jars

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-war-plugin

I am building a war that contains several jars.

By static class dependency analysis (e.g. using `jdeps`) one can see (at least in my cases) that a large number of classes is never called. Therefore, I wonder whether one can unpack all jars and only include those classes into the war that could not be eliminated by static analysis.

How can I unpack the jars and only include the classes that match a given criterion?

Comment: a) There is no guarantee that those classes are never called at runtime (e.g. they could be instantiated via reflection) b) Why don't you delete those classes? :-)

Comment: @DominikSandjaja a) I guess he know that.

Comment: Create your own maven plugin and call jdeps inside it.